# A periodic summation question

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

[image]

The periodic series can be solved by doing [image]
[image]

I understand the solution but it is little lengthy process. Can't we apply any law to get the solution direct?

Comment: Essentially, you could write the above solution, concisely, yet precisely and rigorously in $2$ lines. It looks lengthy but the idea is straight-forward.

Comment: The idea is that you recognise the pattern $\left(\frac11 + \frac12\right) - \left(\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$ for the partial sums.

Comment: But it's about gre question and i need to guess the trick quick  . So I asked if there any short cut :)

Comment: Which "direct laws" do you know about finding the sum of a series directly from its $\Sigma$ representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting the sum and performing an **index shift** gets you there pretty quick.

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{20} a_n
&= \sum_{n=1}^{20} \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right) 
= \sum_{n=1}^{20} \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{20} \frac{1}{n+2} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{20} \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=3}^{22} \frac{1}{n} 
= \sum_{n=1}^{2} \frac{1}{n} - \sum_{n=21}^{22} \frac{1}{n} \\
&= \left(\frac 1 1+\frac 1 2\right) - \left(\frac 1 {21} + \frac 1 {22}\right)
\end{align*}
$$

This is a typical case of a **telescoping sum** as mentioned by Sharkos.

Answer (score 3):

Really, Ahaan Rungta's comment is the best answer.

However, another way to look at it is that this is an instance of the phenomenon of a **telescoping sum**, in which cancellations result in partial sums of a series having a very simple form. Try playing with $$\sum \frac1{n(n+1)}$$

Anyway, in mathematics you have to learn to play with things, and add any tricks you discover to your internal library.